# Can I use arrayToObject on a map results MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a map aggregate pipeline that maps the values but returns an array inside of an array.

```
"Codes": [
    {
        
        "$map": {
            "input": "$$e.content",
            "as": "e1",
            "in": [
                {
                    "thisCode": "$$e1.code",
                    "thisCodeDescription": "$$e1.codeDescroption"
                }
            ]
        }
        
    }
]
```

results to this

```
"Codes": [
    [
        [
            {
                "thisCode": "132",
                "thisCodeExplanation": "code stuff explanation"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

I would like to apply an arrayToObject to it with multiple k, v results versus just one and have tried.

```
"Codes": [
    {
        "$arrayToObject": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$$e.content",
                "as": "e1",
                "in": 
                    {
                        "k": "thisCode",
                        "v": "$$e1.code
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
]
```

to look like this:

```
"Codes": [
    {
        "thisCode": "132
    }
]
```

is there a way to get both of the items in the object by arrayToObject on top of maps results to result in both items versus hard-coding the k and v if there are multiple items in the object?

```
"Codes": [
    {
        "thisCode": "132",
        "thisCodeExplanation": "code stuff explanation"
    }
]
```

Comment: can you add sample document(s) and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Don't over complicate, you don't need $arrayToObject, you just need to remove extra brackets:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    "Codes": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$$e.content",
        "as": "e1",
        "in": {
          "thisCode": "$$e1.code",
          "thisCodeDescription": "$$e1.codeDescroption"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I’ll have to add that there are other elements from other sources that come in as pure objects that need the first bracket.

Comment: well, if you have to, you'd better do, right?